# Why does MongoDB populate method fail in this application?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

I have *Posts* and *Post Categories*, each in its own collection.

The Categories Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cat_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

The Posts schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    short_description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    full_text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'category'
    },
    post_image: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

The controller *method* that displays the posts:

```
exports.displayDashboard = (req, res, next) => {
    const posts = Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
        if(err){
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        } else {
            res.render('admin/index', {
              layout: 'admin/layout',
              website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
              page_heading: 'Dashboard',
              posts: posts
            });
        }
    }).populate({ path: 'category', model: Category })
};
```

If in the view I have:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="d-flex">
            <th class="col-1 pl-2">#</th>
            <th class="col-2">Title</th>
            <th class="col-2">Category</th>
            <th class="col-2">Created</th>
            <th class="col-2">Updated</th>
            <th class="col-3 pr-2 text-right">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% if (posts) { %>
            <% posts.forEach(function(post, index) { %>
                <tr data-id="<%= post._id %>" class="d-flex">
                    <td class="col-1 pl-2">
                        <%= index + 1 %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-2">
                        <a href="/<%= post._id %>" class="text-dark">
                            <%= post.title %>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-2">
                        <%= post.category %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-2">
                        <%= post.created_at.toDateString(); %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-2">
                        <%= post.updated_at.toDateString(); %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-3 text-right pr-2">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a href="../dashboard/post/edit/<%= post._id %>" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-post" data-id="<%= post._id %>">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% }); %>
                <% } else { %>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="5">There are no posts</td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

an object is displayed in The *Category* column (of the posts table):

[image]

Yet, ig I try to display the **category name** using `<%= post.category.cat_name %>` I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'cat_name' of null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First off, mongoose convert your schema internally to lower case letters (e.g. "Category" => categories). The category inside the postSchema therefore should reference "categories" so try that. Have you tested if beside `post._id` you are able to render any other field successfully?

Comment: @rags2riches I tried it. t is not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: I had deleted a category *previously assigned* to a post. The fix is simple (in the view):

```
<%= post.category != null ? post.category.cat_name : 'No category assigned' %>
```

instead of

```
<%= post.category.cat_name %>
```

Many thanks to everyone that got involved for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use async/await operators, since `populate` returns a [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html), which can be awaited. More informations and code examples can be found in the official Mongoose's [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

```js
async function yourAwesomeFunction (req, res, next) {
   try {
      const posts = await Post
         .find({ })
         .populate({ path: 'category' });

      res.render('path/to/layout', { posts: posts });
   } catch (e) {
      // TODO: handle possible errors...
   }
};
```

Comment: I found the problem and posted a **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61255236/4512005)** to it. Check it if interested. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Follow This Code**

> Your Model Name is: Category

```
// Please Define post Schema
category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }

// Your Controller
exports.displayDashboard =async (req, res, next) => {
    const posts =await Post.find().populate('category')
    if(posts){
      res.render('admin/index', {
              layout: 'admin/layout',
              website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
              page_heading: 'Dashboard',
              posts: posts
            })
}
}
```

Comment: You can use async await.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: I found the problem and posted a **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61255236/4512005)** to it. Thanks for the help.